# WPF exe not running on another m/c

Tags: .net, wpf

I've built a wpf application and am trying to run it on another m/c but it wont start on any other m/c except mine. Nothing happens. I keep clicking it and it just stays that way. All the libraries are in the correct folder. I cant figure out whats going wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does the application show up in the processes list?

Comment: no..it doesn't. I've tried the DispatcherunhandledException as well. It doesnt throw anything

Comment: Is anyone else wondering what an "m/c" is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very broad question to answer :) I can suggest the following 
Hook an exception log file to the app. You can do this by subscribing  Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException in the App.xaml.cs and write the exception in to a text file.

Or else try debugging in one of the machine you are getting this issue

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not throwing an exception either